# Count occurrences of a specific word in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have some cells with text. I need to count the occurrences of a specific word (not a list) from those cells.

Example sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WECDbepLtZNwNfUmjxfKlCbLJgjyUBB72yvWDMzDBB0/edit?usp=sharing

So far I found one way to count it in English by using `SUBSTITUTE` to replace all these words with `""`:

```
=(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(B1),UPPER(A5),"")))/LEN(A5)
```

However, I don't know why but it doesn't work in German.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

I just realized that you have [cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963915/count-occurrences-of-a-specific-word-in-google-spreadsheet) on both sites.
I also realized that there is a much **simpler case insensitive formula** for your needs

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(B1:B3), " "), "*heRO*")
```

**OR** *(if in cell `A7` we have `*HeRo*`)*

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(B1:B3), " "), A7)
```

If you want just the word `Hero`, remove the asterisks `*` around it.

It also **works for German** or any language.

---

**Original answer**

In your sheet you mention that the count should be 14.
Considering that, I believe you are looking for a solution to also include words like `heroes` or `Hero`

If you want to include variations of `hero`, like `Hero` or `Heroes` you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", SPLIT(CONCATENATE(ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE( 
     B1:B3,"(([H|h]ero).[a-z]\b)|([H|h]ero)"," @ ♜ "))),char(10))), " "), "♜")
```

If on the other hand want just the word `Hero` or just some cell value you can omit part of the regex "(([H|h]ero).[a-z]\b)|([H|h]ero)" which would now be

"([H|h]ero)" or just `A7` turning the cell depending formula to

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", SPLIT(CONCATENATE(ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(B1:B3,A7," @ ♜ "))),char(10))), " "), "♜")
```

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)